# Exposed Views Combine filter not working

Tags: 8, views

Exposed Views Combine filter is working fine for administrator role, But its showing "Page not found" when I am trying to access with authenticated user role. I rebuild the cache so many times and rechecked the permissions.

For authenticated user its showing result on :
    http://localhost/example/testfilter?combine=&title=abc

But showing "Page not found" on
    http://localhost/example/testfilter?combine=textdata&title=abc

Again for administrator , Both URLs are displaying correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which fields you are combining.

If e.g. you have a user field as combined field, Drupal needs the "Administer users" permission to use this filter.

An issue about this can be found at
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3030696